# Legacy-install-failure while installing tensorflow in M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pip, apple-m1

I have been trying to install TensorFlow 2.6.0 in a conda environment. Here's the command:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.6.0
```

But it gives me this error:

```
    raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
            TypeError: str expected, not int
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

The whole output is too big to fit in here. So I uploaded the full output here - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eKL5UbeK8y0nNbp3mnWPBUutrTOTiWHALjZliQtB7jw/edit?usp=sharing

**Python v3.8.13,
Pip v22.1.2,
OS: macOS Big Sur v11.6.**
Help me solve this.

Comment: Hi @ Arannya, please follow the steps mentioned in this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) to install tensorflow. Ensure that the software and hardware requirements are met and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!